# Janus.Web.GridEX unauthorized license message

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-2.0, vs-web-site-project, janus

I have an asp.net website which contains a Janus grid control. The website was originally developed in VS 2008, and that version is working fine in production. However, I am migrating the site to VS 2012 (using 2.0 Framework) and now when  publish to the test server, I (randomly) get a message "This application is using an unauthorized copy of Janus 'Janus.Web.GridEX.GridEX' control.

I have the license key. I re-installed the Janus controls suite msi package on my machine, and I also added a control to a dummy page so the licenses could get synched. No luck.

I need to fix a bug, so I need to publish this site to test. How can I get rid of the message ? I have contacted Janus, but no response.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your solutions window, look for bin/app_licenses.dll and another file called license.licx

- Delete both these files.
- Recompile.
- Go to a page that contains the Janus Grid, and modify the grid (size, etc).
- Recompile Deploy to
  server